# Use a Class name stored in a variable to call a Class method?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm probably over-thinking this/wasting time trying to avoid a bit of conditional code - so I thought I would ask. I've seen some other questions @ this sort of thing but they were using php or some other language.

At the most basic, can I do something like this (I know the syntax is wrong):

```
        Class * var = @"Playback_Up";
        // call Class method to get default settings
        NSMutableDictionary * dict = [var getPlaybackDefaults];
```

Why do I want to do this? To avoid a bunch of conditionals. I have an app where a using can select from a range of playback "types" - each type is handled by a subclass of a "Playback" class. It would be convenient to store the class names in an array and then when a selection is made (from a tableView) call the selected class, create an instance of it, etc.

Is this possible or am I digging myself into a hole here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for your first line is:

```
Class var = NSClassFromString(@"Playback_Up");
```

The rest is fine, and I use this kind of technique more frequently than you might imagine.

(Except that "Playback_Up" should never be the name of a class of course.)

---

EDIT: Do note Paul.s's comment below. Using `+class` is preferred if you can hard-code the class at compile time.

Comment: or how about `[Playback_Up class]`?

Comment: Yes, that's fine as well (and better if the name is hard-coded). `NSClassFromString` just lets you handle a variable string, which is nice if you're reading it from somewhere else.

Comment: @skinnyTOD It's also useful if you are going in the opposite direction to do the little bit of extra work  `NSStringFromClass([MyClass class]);` so Xcode can actually refactor if you change the name of the class.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! um... why wouldn't you name a class "Playback_Up" :-)

Comment: Classnames should never include a underscore. Naming in Cocoa is a very important thing, and there are parts of the system that rely on proper naming. Even removing the underscore, "PlaybackUp" isn't a noun. Using normal class naming conventions, it suggests that "playback" modifies "up" which is even more confusing. Consider NSMutableArray, NSURLConnection, UIViewController, etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html